# Ошибка composer.phar

Tags: php

Выдало такую ошибку при работе с плагином minify - `You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php php composer.phar install`
Доступа по ssh к серверу нет, как включить этот файл?

Comment: Судя из ошибки - у Вас не установлен composer вообще. Раньше им пользовались? Если нет то выполните команды, которые Вам написали `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php php composer.phar install`

Comment: каким образом выполнить, я сказал, что доступ к хостингу только фтп